# Creation of OAuth User IDs

Tags: python, api, oauth

I am just starting the process of learning to access APIs using Python. Initially I presumed OAuth User IDs were generated or supplied by the API owner somehow. Would it actually be fabricated by myself, using alphanumerics and symbols? This is just for a personal project, I wouldn't have a need for a systematic creation of IDs. The APIs I am working with are owned by TDAmeritrade.

Answer (score 1):

OAuth is has no capabilities for any type of provisioning of users or credentials.

OAuth 2.0 provides for the Delegation of Authorization

- By the Resource Owner (User)
- to the OAuth Client (Application)
- for Access to a Resource Server (Website or Api or ???)